# execute stored procedures in pgadmin with datetime parameters

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-functions

I'm a newbie in pgadmin-4, postgressql, I don't know how to execute stored procedures in pgadmin with datetime parameters?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Check(a integer, b integer, startdate timestamp without time zone, enddate timestamp without time zone)
```

How can I excute it.
I has been run:

```
SELECT "Check"(56, 0,'2018-07-07','2018-07-09');
```

But it give me error like this:

function Check(integer, integer, unknown, unknown) does not exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check two things:

```
-- quoted function's name: "Check" 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "Check"(a integer, b integer,
              startdate timestamp without time zone,
              enddate timestamp without time zone)
```

and use explicit cast:

```
-- should work as-is
SELECT "Check"(56, 0,'2018-07-07','2018-07-09');

--with explicit cast
SELECT "Check"(56, 0,'2018-07-07'::timestamp without time zone,
                     '2018-07-09'::timestamp without time zone);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f98009631d2b91bb30fc2a3b8eb3b5e9)**